# Mercurial, stop versioning cache directory but keep directory

Tags: cakephp, mercurial

I have a CakePHP project under Mercurial version control. Right now all the files in the `app/tmp` directory are being versioned, which are always changing.

I do not want to version control these files.

I know I can stop by running `hg forget app/tmp/*`

But this will also forget the file structure. Which I want to keep.

Now I know that Mercurial doesn't version directories, just files, but the CakePHP folks were also smart enough to put an empty file called `empty` in every empty directory (I am guessing for this reason).

So what I want to do is tell Mercurial to forget every file under `app/tmp` except files whos name is exactly *empty*.

What would the command be for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if nothing else works, you can always just ask Mercurial to forget everything, and then revert `empty` before committing:

Here's how I reproduced it, first create initial repo:

```
hg init
md app
md app\tmp
echo a>app\empty
echo a>app\tmp\empty
hg commit -m "initial" -A
```

Then add some files we later want to get rid of:

```
echo a >app\tmp\test1.txt
echo a >app\tmp\test2.txt
hg commit -m "adding" -A
```

Then forget the files we don't want:

```
hg forget app\tmp\*
hg status                     <-- will show all 3 files
hg revert app\tmp\empty
hg status                     <-- now empty is gone
echo glob:app/tmp>.hgignore
hg commit -m "ignored" -A
```

Note that all `.hgignore` does is to prevent Mercurial from discovering new files during `addremove` or `commit -A`, if you have explicitly tracked files that match your ignore filter, Mercurial will still track changes to those files.

In other words, even though I asked Mercurial to ignore `app/tmp` above, the file `empty` inside will not be ignored, or removed, since I have explicitly asked Mercurial to track it.

Comment: I had to change the line `hg revert app\tmp\empty` to `hg revert app\tmp\\*\empty` and `hg revert app\tmp\cache\\*\empty` because it was made up of other directories inside tmp that needed kept. Thanks.

Comment: Also nice to know it will not ignore items your explicitly specified to track.

Answer (score 3):

At least theoretically (I don't have time to try it right now), [pattern matching](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html) should work with the `hg forget` command.  So, you could do something like `hg forget -X empty` while in the directory (`-X` means "exclude").

You may want to consider using .hgignore, of course.

Comment: Just adding them in .hgignore should do exactly what he wants. You just have to be careful running a subsequent `hg purge` (I learned that the hard way, unfortunatey)

Comment: I'll try that out. For the .hgignore would I just put "app/tmp" inside it? Thanks

Comment: @Tim, if I create a file called .hgignore with contents `app/tmp` it will ignore the directory too right? How can I use pattern matching to exclude the `empty` files in the ignore so the directories stay versioned? Thanks!!

Comment: Forget all the files you don't want in there, but leave `empty` as tracked, and add the directory to your ignore filter. This works, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need to do it once I'd just do this:

```
find app/tmp -type f | grep -v empty | xargs hg forget
hg commit
```

from then on just put this in your `.hgignore'

```
^app/tmp
```

Comment: +1 This looks interesting. From my limited knowledge, it looks like it first finds every file in tmp, then filters out the empty files, then passes the remaining list to hg forget. But doesn't xargs limit the list? Would that leave some? Not sure how that works. Also I think a message is required for hg commit. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The first part produces a list of all the files in app/tmp, the second stage removes the ones *named* `empty` from the list, and the third runs `hg forget` on all the filenames left.  You need something slightly fancier if you have spaces in file names or files named `notempty`, but from your description that should do it.

Comment: This worked great for me - thanks. Just commenting on it in case I need to find it again in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial has built-in support for globbing and regexes, as explained in the [relevant chapter](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html) in the mercurial book. The [python regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) implementation is used.

This should work for you:

```
hg forget "re:app/tmp/.*(?<!/empty)$"
```